# How to combine two arrays using map/filter/reduce?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects: employees and companies.

```
var employees= [{
    name: 'XYZ',
    empId: 0,
    age: 29,
    compId: 1
}, {
    name: 'ABC',
    empId: 1,
    age: 26,
    compId: 2
}, {
    name: 'EFG',
    empId: 2,
    age: 28,
    compId: 1
}, {
    name: 'MNO',
    empId: 3,
    age: 32,
    compId: 3
}];

var companies = [{
    name: 'Facebook',
    id: 1
}, {
    name: 'Amazon',
    id: 2
}, {
    name: 'Google',
    id: 3
}];
```

By using map/filter/reduce based on these arrays, I have to print a output like

"Employee 'MNO' of Age 32 is working in Google"

These two arrays have in common is 'employees.compId = companies.id'.

Please help me how to relate these two arrays and print the above output string.

Comment: What research have you done? What did you find out from that research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like bellow

```
var sentences = employees.map(function (emp) {
    var company = companies.filter(function (comp) {
        return comp.id === emp.compId;
    })[0];
    return "Employee '" + emp.name + "' of Age " + emp.age + " is working in " + company.name;
});

console.log(sentences);
```

[*demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/ad6kc175/)

Comment: you forgot reduce ... `}).reduce(function(p, s) {
    return p + '\n' + s;
});`
Then you've used map/filter/reduce ... and in the "right" order :p